Can't read/list from a Azure storage Account into Databricks notebooks using Secret Scopes
Despite the fact that I have checked and tested my blob url path in my Azure storage account I'm still getting a: cannot resolve hostname. It's like if my secret scopes were not working. Here is what I have done:

Have my Azure Storage Account and Azure Databricks Service workspace running with a cluster
I have setup my secrets scopes using databricks cli (the python library) from my terminal:

#Installing the databricks cli
pip install databricks-cli
#created a token: 
databricks configure --token

Then on azure databricks: click on my username at top right corner + settings + developer on my left sidebar + click on manage Access tokens button and generated a new token.
Then it asked me for my Databricks Host: https://adb-151anyothernumersinmyurl3420.0.azuredatabricks.net/ (got this from my url browser bar in the azure databricks workspace)
And then asked me for my previous generated token.
Created the scope with: databricks secrets create-scope --scope  (my scope name was emailscontainerstorage)
Confirmed that the scope is create with:
databricks secrets list-scopes
Scope                   Backend     KeyVault URL
----------------------  ----------  --------------
emailscontainerstorage  DATABRICKS  N/A

Then needed to create a key:
databricks secrets put --scope <scop-name> --key <key-name>
In my case:  databricks secrets put --scope emailscontainerstorage --key claveaccesso
A text file was opened and pasted my access key (that i got from my azure storage dashboard under the settings + Access keys), then saved and closed the file.
Confirmed my secret scope with secret key:
databricks secres list --scope emailscontainerstorage
databricks secrets list --scope <scope-name> emailscontainerstorage
Key name        Last updated
------------  --------------
claveaccesso   171234557520

I can confirm that I have access to the scope with:
databricks secrets list-acls --scope emailscontainerstorage
Principal                      Permission
-----------------------------  ------------
info@myazureaccountemail.com  MANAGE

After reading guides created a notebook in scala with this code:
val containerstorageaccess = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "emailstorageaccount", key = "claveaccesso")
val storageaccountname = "submarinobursatil"
val contaninername = "submarinobursatilemails"

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key." + storageaccountname + ".blob.core.windows.net", containerstorageaccess)

val fileName = "sushisommarbella.sxls"

val data = spark.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .csv("wasbs://" + contaninername + "@" + storageaccountname + ".blob.core.windows.net/" +fileName)

display(data)

But i still keep getting error: IllegalArgumentException: Secret does not exist with scope: emailstorageaccount and key: claveaccesso
Did a second try with python:
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.submarinobursatil.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.submarinobursatil.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.submarinobursatil.dfs.core.windows.net", dbutils.secrets.get(scope="emailscontainerstorage", key="claveaccesso"))

Ano since i go no errors then I tried to add 2 more lines:
spark.read.load("abfss://submarinobursatilemails@submarinobursatil.dfs.core.windows.net/emailsfolder")

dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://submarinobursatilemails@submarinobursatil.dfs.core.windows.net/emailsfolder")

And now I get the error even when I'm sure that url path is the correct path to my container file: https://submarinobursatil.blob.core.windows.net/submarinobursatilemails/sushisommarbella.xlsx
This is the error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o421.load.
: Status code: -1 error code: null error message: Cannot resolve hostname: submarinobursatil.dfs.core.windows.netjava.net.UnknownHostException
So I'm lost here, can someone point me out in th right direction so I can simply read and display data on dat excel file, or any type of file so I can start treating searches within these files?
Wha am I doing wrong?
I'm using azure datbricks, azure storage account.
Any insights will be appreciated.
I have tried everything I said and got 2 different errors whether using scala or python. And will need some advice since I can only find old tutorials and this is the new version.

You create the scope named emailscontainerstorage but try to read scope emailstorageaccount ?

That was actually the error. All working now. Thanks!

Thank you @ScootCork and @gallo2000sv, Posting your discussion as an answer for the community.

The above error will arise when there is no secret scope created for the given values. So, when this error occurs, cross check whether the scope is created or not with same names.
And coming to the python code, it seems that you are giving your storage account access key in the place of SAS and that might be the reason for the error.
you can set the spark configuration like below using your account access key in the secret scope to avoid the above error.
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<your_storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net",
dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "
emailscontainerstorage", key = "claveaccesso"))

Now, read the file and it will work as expected.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/connect/storage/azure-storage#accountkey
